# Puppeteer doesn't show a calendar that is shown after clicking a text field

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer for doing some web scraping and I'm having troubles. The website I'm trying to scrape is this [one](https://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/reumd-le-meridien-ra-beach-hotel-and-spa) and I'm trying to create a screenshot of a calendar that appears after clicking the button "Reserve now" > "Dates".

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
    void (async () => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
            const page = await browser.newPage();         
            await page.goto('https://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/reumd-le-meridien-ra-beach-hotel-and-spa');
            await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 938 });       
            await page.waitForSelector('.m-hotel-info > .l-container > .l-header-section > .l-m-col-2 > .m-button');
            await page.click('.m-hotel-info > .l-container > .l-header-section > .l-m-col-2 > .m-button');
            await page.waitForSelector('.modal-content');
            await page.waitFor(5000);
            await page.waitForSelector('.js-recent-search-inputs .js-datepick-container .l-h-field-input')
            await page.click('.js-recent-search-inputs .js-datepick-container .l-h-field-input');
            await page.waitFor(5000);
            await page.screenshot({ path: 'myscreenshot.png'});
            await browser.close();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

})()
```

This is what myscreenshot.png should contain:

[image]

but I'm getting this instead:

[image]

As you can see, myscreenshot.png doesn't contain the calendar. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since I click on the right node and I even give time enough to it for loading everything.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I forgot to say that I have also tried [Puppeteer recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/puppeteer-recorder/djeegiggegleadkkbgopoonhjimgehda) in order to achieve this and I haven't had luck either.

Comment: I do not know why, but I cannot reproduce the issue on Windows 7 x64 with puppeteer 1.12.2-post (Chrome revision 630727): the screenshot has the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

As you have many `.l-h-field-input` elements, I would try being more specific there.
This worked for me:

```js
await page.click('.js-recent-search-inputs .js-datepick-container .l-h-field-input');
```

Comment: I have just tried your code but it seems to not be working always. I mean, the first time I ran it, the screenshot didn't have the calendar but the second time yes. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: You could try launching the browser with headless in false so you can see how the browser behaves (`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});`)

Comment: Ok, this is what I have got: https://i.imgur.com/5HbwuLq.png also, I have updated the code on my main post to the code I currently have.